# Image hover overlay: handle the opacity of nested element

Tags: css, hover, overlay

I have this situation which doesn't work as desired:

```css
.work-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background: #eee;
}

.overlay-info:hover {
  opacity: .75;
}

.go-to {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="work-container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/320/240" class="img-responsive">
  <div class="overlay-info">
    <div class="go-to">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When hovering over the image, the `.overlay-info` div gets the `opacity` of `.75` (it starts at `0`), but I'd like for the `button` to have the `opacity` of `1`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use rgba instead of opacity, if you use opacity, children of the element which set opacity will inherit